# How do I get my game on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, construct-2

I am trying to upload my game to Facebook. However, the game does not appear. Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to the site. In future, please be more specific on the problem. What have you tried to solve the problem? What is the error messages? Have you tried searching the error message in Google? What did you find? What did you try? By answering these questions, you will get better answers.

Answer (score 4):

You can't upload a game on Facebook. You need to host the game on your own server with SSL capabilities, and then Facebook will show the game from your server to the players.

You seem to be using Construct 2. There is a great [tutorial](https://www.scirra.com/tutorials/58/how-to-make-a-facebook-game) for publishing a Construct 2 game on Facebook. Just follow the tutorial and you should be all set.

Comment: thank you.. i already put game on web server, however error occur.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: im using 5gbfree as a web server... then, SSL error has been display.game do not display at all.. how to solve it?

Comment: @Muhammadshahril You need SSL enabled host. Contact 5gbfree and ask how do you enable the SSL.

Comment: Please avoid extended discussion in comments, especially discussion that is better suited to the technical support staff of your web host.

Comment: ok, i will try it first..

Comment: 5gbfree not yet give any respons, i still do not know to solve the problem..